# jQuery Mobile Detect Home Screen Bookmark

Tags: jquery-mobile

I know there's no way to add a home screen bookmark automatically within a mobile web app, however, is there a way to DETECT if one has been created?

Answer (score 0):

You could prompt the user to bookmark your app and then save their response ([seen here on Mobile Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate/blob/master/doc/misc.md)). This would allow you to "detect" if they have already added it.

> The Mobile Bookmark Bubble is a JavaScript library that adds a promo
>   bubble to the bottom of your mobile web application, inviting users to
>   bookmark the app to their device's home screen. The library uses HTML5
>   local storage to track whether the promo has been displayed already,
>   to avoid constantly nagging users.